# SSRS (Column Chart): Showing column bar with Zero(0) lable for non Existing data in bind dataset

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am new to SSRS.

I have created a Aging Column chart by category, by switch case in category group expression like Category group on:

```
=Switch( Fields!Age.Value>=0 and Fields!Age.Value<=7,1,
 Fields!Age.Value>=8 and  Fields!Age.Value<=14,2,
 Fields!Age.Value>=15 and  Fields!Age.Value<=21,3,
 Fields!Age.Value>=22 and  Fields!Age.Value<=31,4,
 Fields!Age.Value>31,6)
```

My problem is, if Data set bind with chart do not have any row for a particulate category (like "8-14 Days") then chart is not showing data for in with 0 value:

My requirement is if no data available for a age category, Zero(0) value is to be displayed like:

[image: required prototype]

Chart Description are:

Values = Count(id)
Category : Group on

```
 =Switch(Fields!Age.Value>=0 and Fields!Age.Value<=7,1,
     Fields!Age.Value>=8 and  Fields!Age.Value<=14,2,
     Fields!Age.Value>=15 and  Fields!Age.Value<=21,3,
     Fields!Age.Value>=22 and  Fields!Age.Value<=31,4,
     Fields!Age.Value>31,6)
```

Series: No Series.

Comment: Can you change the query instead?  Please post the SQL query.

Comment: @tgolisch thanks for reply yes i can, My query is very simple,its structure is like "Select StudentId , Age from student", everything i did on SSRS chart.

Comment: The solution to this old question doesn't seem all that related to the question, so I wonder if this would be worth closing as "cannot be reproduced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for your help.
I have achieve my requirement  by using Temp SQl Tables, but your guidance is really helpful.
thanks again.

:)